# Groovy does not like Reflections Constructor taking null args

Tags: java, groovy, reflection, null

I have created a [`groovy-reflection-troubleshooting` repo](https://github.com/bitbythecron/groovy-reflection-troubleshooting) to reproduce this entirely and easily.

---

Basically this Groovy code runs fine:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName('troubleshooting.DangWidget')
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(Configuration)
Object testClassInstance = constructor.newInstance(new Configuration())
// Object testClassInstance = constructor.newInstance(null)
```

But this throws an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName('troubleshooting.DangWidget')
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(Configuration)
// Object testClassInstance = constructor.newInstance(new Configuration())
Object testClassInstance = constructor.newInstance(null)
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I guess I'm wondering why I can't pass `null` into `constructor.newInstance(null)` and what I can pass `constructor.newInstance` if I truly wish to pass the new instance the value `null`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newInstace` takes a varargs argument. When you call it with a `null`, it's interpreted as a `null` array - i.e., no arguments, and since your class doesn't have such a default constructor, the call fails.

One way to solve this is to explicitly pass an array with a single `null` element, representing the one argument the constructor has:

```
Object testClassInstance = constructor.newInstance([null] as Configuration[])
```

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik (+1) but your suggestion still doesn't work (same exception). Check it out for yourself by cloning the repo...any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb yeah, my bad. Old Java habits I guess - although my reasoning was sound, my solution definitely was not. Please see my edited answer for a solution that does work.